# What is this lazy execution approach (using lambda) also known as?

Tags: python

```
import time

start_time = time.time()  # get current time
request_time = lambda: "%.5fs" % (time.time() - start_time)

time.sleep(10)

result = request_time()
```

`result` will be the difference of the present value of time
instead of the lambda creation time.

What is this lazy concept also known as? Is it the same as late binding/closure concept in Python, as explained in [Common Gotchas – Late Binding Closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)?

Comment: "defining and calling a function" ?

Comment: Really, this is no different than defining a function using `def`, and this behavior is just like it is in any other language. Functions' code is executed at call time, not at definition time.

Comment: `lambda` is an anonymous function. Since you're assigning it to variable, it's not an anonymous anymore and acts like regular function. After your `sleep()` you're just calling function, there's nothing related to lazy concept.

Comment: What I mean to ask is that - is this exactly the same as - https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures - in this link you will notice that the value of i is evaluated when the function is invoked. And in the case of my question the value of time.time() is evaluated at the time of invocation also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that `time.time()` is only called when the function `request_time` is called is not a consequence of late binding, but the normal function definition and calling behaviour (I don't know what the proper computer science term for this concept is).

What late binding means is that the names `time.time` and `start_time` are only looked up at the time when `request_time` is called, not when it is defined.

Since neither `time.time` nor `start_time` change between the function definition and the function call, it doesn't make a difference.

However, for example this would make a difference:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()  # get current time
request_time = lambda: "%.5fs" % (time.time() - start_time)

time.sleep(10)

start_time = time.time()  # get current time again
result = request_time()
```

Now, `result` would be a very small time difference, not ca. 10 seconds, since `start_time` has been redefined.

Or, if you did

```
del time
request_time()
```

you would get `NameError: name 'time' is not defined`, even though it *was* defined when `request_time` was defined.

Also, this has nothing to do with using `lambda` and you would get the same results if you used a normal function definition instead:

```
def request_time():
    return "%.5fs" % (time.time() - start_time)
```